# How to import a map defined in an external json file?

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript

I have the following json file containing a configuration:

```
{
   "config1": { //this would be a map
      "a": [ "string1", "string2"],
      "b": [ "string1", "string2"]
   }
}
```

Prior to migrating to typescript the following worked:

```
import * as myConfig from './config.json';
...
myConfig.config1[this.state.section]; //section would be either "a" or "b"
```

Now the code gives me:

> Element implicitely has an "any" type because blablabla has no index signature

Note that I made sure that the following are set in my tsconfig file:

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
"resolveJsonModule": true,
```

But it still doesn't work.
What am I missing?

**Edit:**

It seems has something to do with runtime validation, the following seems fine:

```
myConfig.config1["a"]; //alright!
```

but this is not:

```
const name:string = "a";
myConfig.config1[name]; //NOT!
```

regardless I need to pass a variable..how can I do that? :(

Comment: In order to make bracket notation working your config define an index signature like `interface IData {
    [ key: string ]: object;
}`

You can read more about it https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a asterisk any more. Starting Typescript 2.9 (I can be wrons about specific version) you can do just `import myConfig from './config.json';`

If you still have this issue I guess there is no typedef for your config file so typescript transpiler can't get what is the structure of your imported object.

- create `@types` directory inside `src` folder of your project
- create `myConfig.d.ts` inside of `@types`
- define the structure of your config file in `myConfig.d.ts` like:

```
declare module "myConfig.json" {
   const config: object;
   export default config;
}
```

In order to make "bracket notation" working your config type should define an index signature like:

```
interface IConfig {
    [ key: string ]: object;
}
```

You can read more about it https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Comment: You mean inside of the "src" folder?

Comment: Doesn't work: the problem is about using a variable to refer to a key, see edit :(